# Ordering without including NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, sql-order-by

I have a column called Weight which includes NULLS. I want to order the column by Ascending. But when I do so, rows that contain NULLS comes at the top. I do not want this to happen. I want to eliminate the rows that have NULLS for the sorting procedure. In other words, I want to sort the rows which have numerical values only. Currently, I am having following code

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Name], [Weight]  
FROM [SalesLT].[Product] 
ORDER BY [Weight];
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. Where should NULL values end up, scattered in random places around the result set? Please edit the question and provide an example of expected output.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have figured it out. Please do check this. Here I'm using `WHERE`to eliminate NULLS.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Name],[Weight]  
FROM [SalesLT].[Product] 
where [Weight] is not null
ORDER BY [Weight]
```

Comment: If that is what you wanted that is a very poorly written question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future. Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.